# Design/Architecture for MVC WinForms Dialog Control/Use

Tags: c#, mvc, winforms

All I have built an MVC WinForms application where Views are blind and deaf of their controllers. To facilitate this I have used Ninject as my Dependency Injection (DI) Inversion of Control (IoC) container. I have a question regarding my design/architecture of the way I handle showing dialogs (remembering I want full testability for all components).

I have two "marker" interfaces for the controllers and views of dialogs. The controller interface is:

**IDialogController.cs**:

```
public interface IDialogController : IDisposable { }
```

Made disposable to enusure the view is cleaned up when we use `using(saveDialogController){ ... }`. The view interface is **IDialogView.cs**:

```
public interface IDialogView { }
```

I then have my **ISaveDialogView.cs** as:

```
public interface ISaveDialogView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load the items to be displayed in the ListView.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">The items to display.</param>
    void LoadItemList(IEnumerable<string> items);
}
```

and the *actual* view that uses this interface is **SaveDialogView.cs**:

```
public partial class SaveDialogView : Form, ISaveDialogView, IDialogView
{
    public SaveDialogView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
        Close();
    }

    private void buttonNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
        Close();
    }

    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        Close();
    }

    public void LoadItemList(IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        listBoxItems.DataSource = items;
    }
}
```

and the **SaveDialogController.cs** is:

```
public class SaveDialogController : IDialogController
{
    private ISaveDialogView view = null;

    public SaveDialogController(ISaveDialogView view)
    {
        if (view == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("view");

        this.view = view;
        Log.Trace("SaveDialogController.Ctor(): Initialized successfully");
    }

    public DialogResult ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner, IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        view.LoadItemList(items);
        using ((Form)view)
        {
            var result = ((Form)view).ShowDialog();
            Log.Trace($"SaveDialogController.ShowDialog(): " + 
                "DialogResult.{result.ToString()} returned from view");
            return result;
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Members.
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (view != null)
                {
                    ((Form)view).Dispose();
                    view = null;
                    Log.Trace("SaveDialogController.Dispose(): View disposed");
                }
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion // IDisposable Members.
}
```

I can then call the dialog from another controller as follows:

```
using (SaveDialogController c = DialogControllerFactory.GetController<SaveDialogController>())
{
    DialogResult result = c.ShowDialog((Form)View, new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" });
    // Do stuff...
}
```

My questions on this are as follows:

1. Is this design/architecture okay, could it be made better, if so, how?
2. Are there any problems with the way I am disposing the view/`Form` here?
3. Any other comments?

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly do you archive with that architecture.
In the example code above, the controller doesn't have any logic - so you can just drop it and use the dialog directly.

However, if that is just an example and you add more logic to the controller lets take a short look to the following method:

```
public DialogResult ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner, IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    view.LoadItemList(items);
    using ((Form)view)
    {
        var result = ((Form)view).ShowDialog();
        Log.Trace($"SaveDialogController.ShowDialog(): " + 
            "DialogResult.{result.ToString()} returned from view");
        return result;
    }
}
```

- If the mehtod `ShowDialog` is called, the view (instance variable) will be disposed (because: `using ((Form)view)`) . If the method is called again, it works on a disposed view. If the controller will be disposed later, it tries to dispose the view again. So you dont need the using here.
- If you cast your abstraction against the concrete class (`((Form)view)`), the abstraction is valueless because you can not mock it in unit tests. To avoid casting, add all needed methods (in that case `ShowDialog`) to your abstraction.
- The instance variable `view` should be readonly because it is initialized once in constructor.